# Padding ASP Textbox

Tags: html, asp.net, css, padding

I currently have an issue with that. There is a lot of excess padding to the right of my webpage (http://openset.azurewebsites.net/).I would like the page to fit on the screen. After doing some investigative work, I have found the object that is causing it and it is my `<asp:TextBox/>` in which the user inputs their email address. After searching the CSS I cannot find any sort of excess `padding` attribute for the TextBox and am at a loss as  how to correct it.

**The code concerned is**:

```
<div class="pull">
    <asp:TextBox ID="AddEmailName" runat="server" Text="Enter your e-mail here"
                 onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter your e-mail here') this.value = '';"
                 onblur="if(this.value == 'Enter your e-mail here' || this.value == '') this.value = 'Enter your e-mail here';"
                 style="text-align:center" Width="300px" Font-Size="Large"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="AddEmailButton" runat="server" width="100px"
                backcolor="#c7b099" forecolor="#000" Text="Notify Me"
                OnClick="AddEmailButton_Click" CausesValidation="true" />
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
.pull {
    position: relative;
    left: 525px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `left: 525px` moves the div, but the width stays at 100%. You should use `padding-left: 525px` or `margin-left: 525px` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
  .pull {
     position: relative;
     Padding-left: 525px;
    }
```

you need add `padding-left` or `Margin-left` as someone said..